# How to configure SSO for Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

As per [Azure AD B2C documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso) we can configure SSO for Azure AD B2C application. We want our user to do self-registration for the application thus opted for AD B2C.

However after creating B2C tenant account and configuring all the policies. I am unable to find option to configure SSO. Since after 30th Nov 2017, Active Directory will only be available in new portal. Kindly provide reference wrt new portal.

[image: Image after configuring 2 application in B2C]. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSO integration in Active Directory is totally different from SSO integration in an application through AD B2C. It took some time for me to verify all the links and steps. Hope this will help others.

Below are the steps to configure SSO in AD B2C. Create AD B2C and configure all the policies.

1. Once you have configured all your policies go to ALL policies node, it will list all the present policies in your application. Then click on singin policy. Alternatively you can directly click on sign in policy. 
   [image]
2. Once you click the EDIT option, you will see the option for 'Token, session and single sign-on configuration'. Configure those and you are done to use SSO.
   [image]

For more details about the token, session and sso config please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso)

3. Create couple of application to verify that the SSO is working fine.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 2):

As the document in the your question said,if you have multiple applications and policies in your B2C tenant, you can manage user interactions across them using the Single sign-on configuration property. You can also add external identity provider like Google, Facebook and etc.

If you want to know how it works and how to configure SSO in Azure AD B2C, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-sso-custom).

Also, If you want to configure SSO for applications in your B2C tenant(the Directory).

1. Go to Azure portal > Enterprise applications> Add Non-gallery applications or in  applications in  Gallery.
2. After adding apps in Enterprise applications, you can select your app and enable SSO for it.

[image]

Hope this helps!

---

**Update**

Adding custom applications requires Azure AD Premium.

[image]

You can also [active Azure Active Directory Premium free for one month](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/trial/get-started-active-directory/).

Now, you can add your own custom applications in Enterprise Applications and then configure SSO for it:

[image]

Comment: thanks for replying @Wayne Yang -MSFT. However I am getting error "Failed to activate Azure AD Premium trial" thus cannot validate your solution. I will update once the error is gone. FYI: I am using 30 days Azure Trail. Thanks.

Comment: Hi,@Ankit Kumar. You can use SSO in your free account but just can use SSO for 10 apps per user. You can post a screenshot to me.Also, If you have any process or issue, don't be shy to let me know it .

Comment: When I created a new ADB2C tenant, It created a new directory in the account and I have registered couple of application(snap in qn). I have also configured all the policies so that it can be used in the application. Now when I am trying to click on the Azure Active Directory node in the default menu to register my same app as enterprise application (selecting Non gallery option), It gives me a message "Get a free Premium trial to use this feature" When I try to active the trail I am getting "Failed to activate Azure AD Premium trial" trail. I just wanted to configure couple of apps for my POC

Comment: I have tried to explain the situation in which I am struck right now. @Wayne Yang - MSFT, Do let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Hi, @AnkitKumar . Sorry for my unclear reply, I miss that It did has a limit for using SSO for self-registration Application in Azure AD.. Adding custom application requires Azure AD premium. We can just use SSO for the applications in Gallery.  I will update in my answer to make it clear.

Comment: Hi @WayneYang-MSFT, Thanks for updating the answer, It seems now we are on the same page. The issue which I am facing is "Failed to activate Azure AD Premium trial", When I tried to active it. Its the same error I am getting from yesterday and not able to proceed.

Comment: @AnkitKumar. Yes ,Azure AD Premium need to pay for the license. Also you can try to active the Azure Active Directory Premium free for one month. You can try in this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/trial/get-started-active-directory/  I can active it in my work around, please let me know  if  it can work for you.

Comment: Its Weird. I have the Azure AD Premium trail activated in my default directory(not B2C). With other B2C directory, activating AD Premium trail is giving error. Not sure whats wrong here.

Comment: HI,@AnkitKumar . One account can only active one AD premium  free for month. Since you have already activated one in your Default directory, you cannot active another one in the B2C directory. But you can try to active `Enterprise Mobility+Security` for free one month in the B2C directory. This license contains Azure AD premium. Also please let me know if it can work for you.

Comment: HI,@AnkitKumar . May I know that  have  you test it successfully?

Comment: Hi @WayneYang-MSFT, I am yet to test it. **Enterprise Mobility+Security** needs a work account to activate. My work account is having a very limited access. Just trying to get another trail account to test all the changes.

Comment: @AnkitKumar , OK, I did a test and succeed.  I hope you could do it as well.  Please feel free to talk with me if you have any idea or process.Also, if this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as answer , so that we can help more communities. Thanks!