# Single Sign On with AzureADB2C and B2B

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to configure single sign on to work with for both AzureB2C and B2B tenant?

I know it can be configured for AzureAD B2C and definitely it works for AzureB2B.

Is there a way a user in my B2C tenant perform single sign on also to application in my B2B tenant?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanted your user to sign in on both B2B and B2C tenant with same email Yes you can do it.

As you know how to configure it on [B2C tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324231/how-to-configure-sso-for-azure-ad-b2c)

> [Azure B2B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/index) allows one organization to invite members from other
>   organizations to share application access. It’s only one of its
>   service features. You may know more about B2B user [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/user-properties)

***Now in your case*** you can add your user B2C user here in B2B tenant or vice-versa. There is an option on [azure portal](https://portal.azure.com)  **New Guest User** both on B2C and b2B tenant. You can easily add them up.

See the screen shot below:

[image]

Once they received invitation they would able to access the resource what they are assigning to.

**User Invitation Using MS Graph**

You can also do the same operation using [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0)

You even can create a Custom user flow for newly added user. For more outline you could check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows)

**Points To Remember For B2B**

> Before configuring user invitation be care about below notes!

[image]

> **Note:** If you still have any confusion about work around for B2B and
>   B2C you could also refer this [document](https://predica.pl/blog/azure-ad-b2b-b2c-puzzled-out/)

Comment: @AYODEJI BABAJIDE You could try  this way around, if you have any more query feel free to ask.

Comment: Just to point out that the guest user option on B2C is only for adding extra admin. users. These users cannot sign into an application in the same way that local account users can.

Comment: @nzpcmad Thanks for your enhancement.