# Azure B2C how to mantain user session between a .net web app and a SPA(react)

Tags: c#, reactjs, single-page-application, azure-ad-b2c

We are using Azure B2C to manage authentication in our c# .net web app through Open Web Interface for .NET (OWIN) middleware components.

We also have a SPA on react and here we are using MSAL.js to authenticate the user

the SPA is gonna be open from the #.net web and we want to maintain the user session between these 2 apps.

currently, the user has to login when he goes from the .net app to the SPA or vice-versa, even if the user was already login

if somebody can point me out in the correct direction I'll appreciate

Answer (score 1):

- [Configure session behavior in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior) (includes 'User Flow' and 'Custom Policy' in separate tabs)
- [Single sign-on session management in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso)
- [How to configure SSO for Azure AD B2C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324231/how-to-configure-sso-for-azure-ad-b2c)

For example, below is in signin user flow.
[image]